# AWS RDS, NODE + MYSQL connection not released

Tags: mysql, node.js, amazon-web-services, express, amazon-rds

Our DB is hosted in AWS RDS.
Backend is Nodejs, Mysql, ExpressJs
We followed the same as below [node-mysql-doc](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mysql#pooling-connections)

```
var mysql = require('mysql');
var pool  = mysql.createPool({
  connectionLimit : 10,
  host            : 'example.org',
  user            : 'bob',
  password        : 'secret',
  database        : 'my_db'
});
 
pool.query('SELECT 1 + 1 AS solution', function (error, results, fields) {
  if (error) throw error;
  console.log('The solution is: ', results[0].solution);
});
```

when we hit API to get data, the DB connection touched almost max-connection exceeds
here is the graph of AWS RDS DB Connection

[image]

even though we didn't use the APIs again for 2hours, but still the connections are not released.
It got reduced when we restart the node server.

how to release the connection that showed in AWS graph

Comment: What is the question here? Are you wanting your nodejs service to periodically disconnect all connections from your DB connection pool?

Comment: because connections are not released, got max_connection exceeds error. even for 2user usage.

Comment: You explicitly configured connection pool. Part of the point of pools is that they are always connected. If you don't desire this behavior, you can switch to not using pooling, reduce your pool count per worker process, or increase max connections in the DB.